# How much does using htaccess files slow down website performance (especially with solid state disks)?

Tags: linux, performance, apache, .htaccess

The Apache docs say (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html),

> "You should avoid using .htaccess files completely if you have access
>   to httpd main server config file. Using .htaccess files slows down
>   your Apache http server. Any directive that you can include in a
>   .htaccess file is better set in a Directory block, as it will have the
>   same effect with better performance."

But that gives me no idea of the scale of the impact.

I have an architecture designed for shared hosting where the only choice was to use htaccess files.

I'm moving over to Digital Ocean where I can do what I like.

I need to make a judgement on whether to stick with htaccess files or move stuff from there into the centralized config files and switch them off.

There could be 100s of small low-use sites (local businesses).

If the performance hit amounts to under about 50ms in serving a page or has some other minor hit like reducing the number of concurrent accesses that can be supported by under about 5%, then I don't care.

If the effect is big enough that people might feel the difference, then I care enough to spend time changing things.

But I've found nothing that gives me an indication of what order of magnitude of the hit I can expect.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Edit: I'm not looking for anything like exact numbers. But surely someone somewhere who is more able than me has done some benchmarking, or knows from experience the type of difference there can be under particular circumstances.

Comment: .htaccess is parsed on each request, httpd.conf is parsed once on startup. .htaccess files are scanned for in all parent directories too and parsed if exists, again on each request. Its much better to use the proper config

Comment: Yes I know all that. But how noticable will the effect be?

Comment: And i am surprised to see no one casted a vote on any of the question, answer or comment. :)

Comment: @IdidntKnewIt The question has very few views. Maybe not many people are interested or its hard to search for? For now I'm continuing with htaccess because of the simple flexibility it gives when there are many sites, and the amount of work I'd need to do to change everything when maybe nobody would even notice - I still have no idea what difference it would make!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From an [answer on Quora](http://qr.ae/TUGSqc) by [Jonathan Klein](https://www.quora.com/profile/Jonathan-Klein-1), 12ms for a 1500 line `.htaccess` file:

> Having a large .htaccess does have a cost.  Ours is currently ~1500 lines and we benchmarked the time spent parsing it at around 10-12ms on a production webserver.  Hardware makes a difference obviously, but you can fairly safely assume that the cost of that 3000 line .htaccess is around 25-35ms per request.

Comment: After all this time, an answer to the actual question. I've changed my accepted answer to this. I do think the answer could be improved though: 1. It surely won't be 12ms in most cases, so it won't be strictly correct, but it does give a feel for the scale of the effect, which is what I was hoping for; 2. The link goes to a Quora question with the answer actually pre-dating my question. It should survive. But if it doesn't, this answer will become one that will need to be taken on faith more than it does now. So I suggest summarising the Quora answer to give a sense of how meaningful it is.

Comment: By the sounds of it, this is 12ms for the `.htaccess` file vs no directives at all. What about `.htaccess` vs the same/equivalent directives in the server config? (Which would seem to be the real underlying question - and I imagine would be considerably less?)

Comment: "line" is a horrible unit. Can't just one guy simply say a filesize? Bytes can be compared quite better and nobody has to guess how long the lines are.

Answer (score 7):

That [slide](http://thomaslohner.github.io/slides/Performance-Myths/#/8) shows the impact of htaccess files with either no htaccess file, the htaccess file in the root folder as well as in subfolders in comparison to the no htaccess baseline.

Answer (score 4):

A Digital Ocean tutorial at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-htaccess-file says,

> "The .htaccess page *may* slow down your server somewhat; for most servers this will probably be an imperceptible change."

Answer (score 3):

The httpd.conf is parsed one time. If you use .htaccess it'll get hit every time something is called. That'll cause a fairly large performance hit that will just get worse with increasing requests.

Comment: What do you mean by "fairly large"?

Comment: Does it really matter though? Best practices dictate you should just use httpd.conf.

Comment: It matters because changing the architecture will take time (which equates to money) and risk breaking something that currently works. That's the cost. If the benefit is 40ms shaved off serving a page, it isn't worth that cost. Can you just give some sort of idea of the impact, or don't you know? You must have had something in mind when you said "fairly large" - large enough that the difference would be noticable to a visitor (like 100ms or more)?

Comment: The number would depend on a lot of things. Number of hits, I/O performance, other processes, etc. The cost of not doing it correctly the first time will in the end cost you more money. httpd.conf vs .htaccess isn't an architectural change, it's a simple configuration change. You can literally pull the entries out of the .htaccess and paste them into your httpd.conf.

Comment: This is migrating something that already works from a shared server environment where there's no access to httpd.conf and so no choice (as my question says). Not changing it won't cost anything. Changing it will. Manually copying htaccess entries won't work as they are generated depending on individual site configuration and regenerated if that is changed. If you can answer the original question, please do - even something highly qualified and vague (as in 'can add anything between x and y ms') would be helpful. If you can't, let's leave it there because this is getting nowhere.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are being aggressive about it. You mentioned you were moving it to digital ocean so you could do what you like. You haven't provided what kind of traffic you are expecting or anything about the infrastructure your application sits on. There just isn't enough information to give you exact or even vague numbers.

Answer (score 3):

I quote from a tutorial on .htaccess by Joseph Pecoraro on [code.tutsplus.com here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-ultimate-guide-to-htaccess-files--net-4757):

> Also, when [.htaccess is] enabled the server will take a potential
>   performance hit. The reason is because, every server request, if
>   .htaccess support is enabled, when Apache goes to fetch the requested
>   file for the client, it has to look for a .htaccess file in every
>   single directory leading up to wherever the file is stored.
>
> These potential file accesses (potential because the files may not
>   exist) and their execution (if they did exist) will take time. Again,
>   my experience is that it's unnoticeable and it doesn’t outweigh the
>   benefits and flexibility that .htaccess files provide developers.

For your scenario, my personal recommendation would be like "Don't fix what isn't broken", because time and effort is equal to money, and I fully agree with [your reasoning in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25063677/how-much-does-using-htaccess-files-slow-down-website-performance-especially-wit#comment38995291_25064109).

Comment: I've changed my accepted answer to a recent one that actually answers the question as I originally hoped for. I still think this is a fine answer though.

Comment: @NickRice That's better for everyone :) Thanks for the heads up, but no need. We are all here to learn from each other.

Comment: What's the cost of searching for the .htaccess file? The server has already read the directory to search for whichever file it needs from it (a file, or another directory on the way to one that contains the file), so the file system should have it cached. So it should be a switch to kernel mode, a binary search for ".htaccess", and return not-found. Its not free (read: requires CPU cycles and RAM access), but I don't expect it to be high.

Answer (score -1):

It is hard to give numbers as the impact depends on the speed of your hardware and how much memory are you willing to dedicate for file caching, but let me give you an example that should clarify the impact - let say you have a wordpress site and an image which is located at /wp-content/uploads/2015/10/my.png needs to be served.

While serving this file might take 1 disk access, just to check out for all the possible .htaccess you will need additional 5 disk accesses. If the file is big the overhead might not be noticeable, but for a small file that might even fit into one block on the disk you waste 80% of the time doing things that are not needed at all.

Still, big enough cache can fix almost any design/coding problem, but the more directories you will have the bigger the cache that you will need to avoid degradation of performance.

In your specific case it is actually a no brainer at all. You already generate the htaccess files so all you need to do is wrap them in a directory directive, generate them into some directory and include them from http.conf. Even doing it manually should not take more then a few hours and after that you have a better architecture of your server.