# Writing .htaccess file with php to update AJAX allow from urls

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, .htaccess

I'm working to create some embeds for articles on a site. The embeds call a Javascript file that figures out which article to grab from my site and makes an AJAX call to the appropriate JSON file to grab the article, parse it and then display it.

I also have a member system going which will allow people to sign up for an account telling me what site they will use the embeds on.

What I want to do is have an .htaccess file on the root folder of these JSON files so that only approved members can use the embed which makes AJAX calls to these JSON files.

The .htaccess file will have a list of allow urls that can AJAX to the folder. The thing is it will have to be updated as members are added and deleted.

What's the best way to constantly update this .htaccess file with PHP?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

why dont make your checks with php and hand out the files with php?
its very bad practice to create rule for every single member and also will slow down the server

Comment: I did think about having a php script to reroute and have permissions and such but my boss didn't want the server load for that since every time an embed would be loaded the php script would have to run.

Comment: If an embed is getting 100,000 views that means that each view loaded the php script slowing down the server.

Comment: your just checking userpermissions - .htaccess rules produces much more load, since its parsed everytime for any page loaded. its live parsed by apache - would be better if the rules are in the vhost container then. anyway.. if you want to create a htaccess file php file_put_contents and file_get_contents are the functions you need

just get the content, append your new rules or recreate from the scratch (string appending) and then write it to the disk.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25063677/how-much-does-using-htaccess-files-slow-down-website-performance-especially-wit