# CORS htaccess to only allow certain urls to AJAX to files on a folder and subfolders

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

Does anyone know of what I would set an htaccess file as so that only certain urls can access the files in a folder and subfolders inside of it through AJAX. I don't want to allow everyone open access to it. Only certain URLs.

Thanks!

**Update**

I've come up with an htaccess script that almost works, except it won't apply to all subdirectories. I know my directory command isn't right because if I take it off the server works, but with it throws a 500 error.

Here is my script

```
<Directory /var/www/html/mysite/embed_json/*/>
    <FilesMatch "\.json$">
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(thedomain.com|facebook.com|thehurts.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0$1
            Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
        </IfModule>
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>

<Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
</Files>
Options All -Indexes
```

Comment: Could you please give more specifics? Perhaps an example of what you want to achieve. Also, questions on SO are generally expected to show [research](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What steps have you taken to try to solve your problem?

Comment: Hi @Praveen, here are more details on what I'm working to accomplish. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39193137/writing-htaccess-file-with-php-to-update-ajax-allow-from-urls I have been doing tons of research on apache htaccess headers. Haven't fully figured it out yet but getting close on it.

Comment: @Praveen I added a sample script but my directory command isn't working right so that the htaccess affects all subdirectories and files.

Answer (score 2):

This will likely work for you

```
RewriteCond  !^/path/to/allow/?$
RewriteRule ^folderToDeny/?$ - [F,L]
```

Comment: That would allow all files in the sub tree folders? And what headers would I set for allow origin?

Comment: You would have to modify the regex to include/exclude files under that path, its just an example. 

The example basically says if the path is not /path/to/allow then deny access to that folder, using Apache's F flag https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_f 

allow-origin would depend on what you want to allow

Comment: I added a sample script but my directory command isn't working right so that the htaccess affects all subdirectories and files.