# How to forward full URL with PHP?

Tags: php, url, replace

I want following URL:
`http://example.com/subdir/`  (actually there is no 'subdir' directory on the webserver, where 'example.com' is pointing to)
being forwarded to:

```
https://www.example.com/subdir/
```

This is the code in the index.php file in the directory 'example.com' is pointing to:

```
<?php 
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], "example.com") !== FALSE) {
    Header ("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    Header ("Location: https://www.example.com".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
exit; 
?>
```

Problem: The browser says "The requested URL /subdir/ was not found on this server." (which is right, like mentioned above)

How can anyways replace `'http://example.com/subdir/'` with `'https://www.example.com/subdir/'`?

Comment: This is a job for the web server, not PHP. What web server are you using? Apache?

Comment: Either create the `subdir` and put your `index.php` file there, or control this from your webserver. You cannot do this from the root index.

Comment: You can use nginx rewrite rules: https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/ or apache rewrite rules: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html dependent on your environment.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't understand your question. You want to redirect from `http://example.com/subdir/` to `https://www.example.com/subdir/`, you are effectively doing it and you're asking how to do it. :-?

Comment: I want to replace `http://example.com` in whatever URL it might be used with `https://www.example.com`. Maybe with regex replace? But I don't know regex well enough for that...

Comment: How is that different from `"Location: https://www.example.com".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`?

Comment: $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] does not contain the subdirectory

Comment: @gba Unless I'm missing something, It should and it does. The proof is that you get "The requested URL /subdir/ was not found". And, if unsure, you can `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`.

Comment: @Álvaro The index.php mentioned is in the directory that `example.com` points to. When I input `example.com/subdir/` the server is looking for a page in `/subdir/` which actually is not existing. So `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` cannot return `/subdir/`.

Answer (score 0):

Use your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: .htaccess should not be recommended or even used. Including stuff like this in your VirtualHost should always be preferred due to performance reasons. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25063677/how-much-does-using-htaccess-files-slow-down-website-performance-especially-wit for more info on this topic.

Comment: @Xatenev of cause, but only if you have access to the vHost, most common hosting providers don't let you access this file.

Comment: @CodeBrauer I've never heard of people not be able to access their vhost. You can even do that in shared hosting environments. What 'common hosting providers' do you mean? I'd really suggest switching to a different provider if the provider even is not able to add a small rule into the virtual host configuration.

Comment: Please add the lines to force https

Comment: @Xatenev I've worked mostly with HSP services in Spain and, unless you pay for a dedicated server (virtual or physical), you have no other way to configure Apache than `.htaccess` files, save for very specific items like host name and the like. Also, I once tried a cheap hosting plan at GoDaddy and the situation was the same but several years have passed. I presume that first class American providers in 2017 are different.