# .htaccess make loading time very slow

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I try to prevent visitor accessing my asset folder directly from URL and some limitation to protect my asset folder. I use .htaccess to do that. But sometimes I found my website load very slow when loading content / picture file from asset folder. I also use the same .htaccess on my another web but never found an issue like this before.

Here's my htaccess:

```
# disable indexing and executing script with some format
Options -Indexes
Options -ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .php .php3 .php4 .phtml .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .html .sh .cgi

# block all file format except mentioned below
<Files ^(*.jpeg|*.jpg|*.png|*.pneg|*.JPG|*.JPEG|*.PNG|*.PNEG|*.gif|*.pdf|*.doc|*.docx|*.xls|*.xlsx|*.ppt|*.pptx|*.txt)>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Files>

# force server to present all files as
ForceType application/octet-stream
<FilesMatch "(?i).jpe?g$">
    ForceType image/jpeg
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "(?i).jpg$">
    ForceType image/jpeg
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "(?i).JPG$">
    ForceType image/jpeg
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "(?i).JPEG$">
    ForceType image/jpeg
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "(?i).gif$">
    ForceType image/gif
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "(?i).png$">
    ForceType image/png
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "(?i).PNG$">
    ForceType image/png
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "(?i).pdf$">
    ForceType application/pdf
</FilesMatch>
```

I use PHP 5.6 btw. Any clue why this happens? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure but your `filesmatch` rules are redundant.

Comment: Maybe [AllowOverride](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) and a slow disk? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25063677/how-much-does-using-htaccess-files-slow-down-website-performance-especially-wit